# import xarray returns 'No protocol specified'

Tags: python-3.x, pip, conda, python-xarray

I have recently updated my xarray, but now am running into an error when I import it:

```
$ python3
Python 3.8.10 (default, Jun  2 2021, 10:49:15)
[GCC 9.4.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>import xarray
No protocol specified
>>>
```

What does this mean? Does it have something to do with dependencies on something else? I upgraded using pip3.  I do not own this computer, otherwise I would have installed everything with conda. Does pip3 also sort out dependency issues? I heard conda does.. and maybe I should switch over, but I don't want to create a conflict with the other users on the computer.

Maybe this information is also useful:

```
>>> import xarray
No protocol specified
>>> xarray.show_versions()

INSTALLED VERSIONS
------------------
commit: None
python: 3.8.10 (default, Jun  2 2021, 10:49:15)
[GCC 9.4.0]
python-bits: 64
OS: Linux
OS-release: 5.4.0-70-generic
machine: x86_64
processor: x86_64
byteorder: little
LC_ALL: None
LANG: en_US.UTF-8
LOCALE: ('en_US', 'UTF-8')
libhdf5: 1.10.4
libnetcdf: 4.7.3

xarray: 0.19.0
pandas: 1.3.2
numpy: 1.17.4
scipy: 1.3.3
netCDF4: 1.5.3
pydap: None
h5netcdf: 0.7.1
h5py: 2.10.0
Nio: None
zarr: 2.4.0+ds
cftime: 1.1.0
nc_time_axis: None
PseudoNetCDF: None
rasterio: None
cfgrib: None
iris: None
bottleneck: 1.2.1
dask: 2.8.1+dfsg
distributed: None
matplotlib: 3.1.2
cartopy: 0.18.0
seaborn: None
numbagg: None
pint: None
setuptools: 45.2.0
pip: 20.0.2
conda: None
pytest: 4.6.9
IPython: 7.13.0
sphinx: 1.8.5
>>>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error reflects a problem with how your computer's display is configured, not an error with Xarray.

This answer seems to address the [No protocol specified](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/209746/how-to-resolve-no-protocol-specified-for-su-user) message directly.